# using css to selector the text within a strong tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there is a way to use css selector to locate the text inside a strong tag. i have the following html

```
<div id="rr-left-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
<div class="content">
<div class="response-title">
<div class="response-body">
<div class="response-competing">
**<strong>Competing interests: </strong>**
</div>
```

I am trying to use css to locate the text "Competing interests:".

Many thanks,

Comment: There are **lots** of ways. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you trying to style the text inside the `strong` tag or actually **select**` it for some other reason?

Comment: i am trying to assert it for testing purposes. but i need to assert the text is there

Comment: I have no idea what that means...Assert?

Comment: not to worry, iv solved it. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
.response-competing strong {
    /* your CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
strong{
   color:red;
}
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/uVT6y/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
strong{
   /* your CSS rules */
}
```

If you just want to match the  tag inside response-competing class, use:

```
.response-competing strong{
   /* your CSS rules */
}
```